# Approximation using the Taylor series

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

> $$\sqrt{1+2t\sigma\cos\theta+\frac12t^2\sigma^2(3+\cos(2\theta))}=1+t\sigma\cos\theta+\frac12t^2\sigma^2+O(t^3)$$

What is the omitted step between these two equations? The parameter $t$ lies between $0$ and $1$ and it is said that approximation by using Taylor series is used.

Comment: I'd say the Taylor expansion $$(1+x)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2}x^2+O(x^3)$$

Comment: I understand that it is in continuity of your recent post (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1891721). What do you mean by "the omitted step" ? Have you obtained this result through Wolfram Alpha and want to understand how it can be explained ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Good to meet you here again. The above equation is slightly different with the one with I need to work on, but I've found it in [here](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~antoniov/bagelrings.html) and I've found the writer applied the taylor series, but he didn't explain the middle process. I'm a highschool student and I haven't learn about it so I asked here again in order to learn the mechanism to apply on my equation.

Comment: I understand. I congratulate you to be interested by rather complicated expressions like this one. The answer by Olivier Oloa is good.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Is the way proving x in your equation smaller or equal to 1 is squaring all terms of x and do the square root? Is this right even for the non-vector equation, which is this case?

Comment: @JeanMarie Can I ask you one more question? Is the way proving x in your equation smaller or equal to 1 is squaring all terms of x and do the square root? Is this right even for the non-vector equation, which is this case?

Comment: It's hard for me to understand your question.

Comment: @JeanMarie Could you check my new [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891912/taylor-expansion-for-square-root)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use the Taylor series expansion, as $u \to 0$,
$$
\sqrt{1+u}=1+\frac u2-\frac{u^2}{8}+O(u^3)
$$ applying it to $u=2t\sigma \cos \theta+\dfrac 12t^2\sigma^2 (3+ \cos 2\theta) $ as $t \to 0$, observing that
$$
\frac u2-\frac{u^2}{8}=t\sigma \cos \theta+\dfrac 14t^2\sigma^2 (3+ \cos 2\theta)-\frac{4t^2\sigma^2 \cos^2 \theta}{8}+O(t^3).
$$

Comment: One more question, this Taylor series can only be applies when the absolute value of u is smaller or equal to 1 right? And is the way of getting the absolute vale /root(u^2)?

Comment: @7_G.S.N Yes, $|u|<1$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for it to hold.