# Taylor expansion for square root

Tags: taylor-expansion

[image]
Can I apply the Taylor expansion in here? R is a constant, which should be greater or equal to s, s goes from 0 to 1 and t goes from 0 to pi. The problem is I'm not sure I can ascertain that the magnitude of g(x) is smaller than 1, which is a required condition to apply the Taylor expansion.

Comment: Do you know anything else about R besides that it is constant?

Comment: Looks as if it depends on the magnitude of $R$. For $R$ larger than say $4$, yes, you may Taylor-expand, the expansion becoming better the larger the value of $R$

Comment: @Triatticus I forgot to add the other condition. R should be smaller or equal to s.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh But I want to try with the generalised equation. Is it possible when t to start from 2.5 to 3.14, which makes the equation always smaller than 1 in the given condition?

Comment: There might be specific values for which it works out. But it really doesn't look like a good approach. How about putting a factor $\sqrt{4s^2+R^2}$ outside instead? (I presume that in the first equation it should not read $s^2/4$ ?)

Comment: If $R \leq s$, i.e., $s/R \geq 1$ ; this implies that the whole of $g(x)$ is larger than $1$, alas...

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm sorry. I miswrote the question. R should be greater or equal to s.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh I'm sorry, but what do you mean by not reading s^2/4 ?

Comment: There is an error between the first two lines (a misplaced factor of 4 on $s^2$)

Comment: In this case, hope is permitted... I have checked experimentally that if $0<t<\pi$ and $R/s<0.2$, you have $0<g(x)<1$.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh But how comes putting out that factor (4s^2+R^2)^(1/2) simplify the question?

Comment: If you put this factor out the rest may be written as $\sqrt{1+h(s,t)}$ where $h$ is now always smaller than 1. (But is the first line in your calculation correct or not?)

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Actually, the first one is the only correct equation and the 4 should be in the denominator for the all time. I think this correction might make the problem easier as it is now divided by 4 not multiplied by 4. But still, I don't get you. I tried to factor out that  (4s^2+R^2)^(1/2) but I didn't get h(s,t) smaller than one.

Comment: If 4 is in the denominator, my suggestion doesn't work. Any particular reason why you want to Taylor expand ? The expression $\sqrt{s^2/4 + (R+ s\cos(t/2))^2}$ looks quite nice to me without any expansion?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh I want to do the double integration of that function in respect to s and t, while the order doesn't matter. However, integrating straight away without removing the square root goes insanely complicated, as when it is checked using online integration calculators. So I need to definitely remove that square root by using the Taylor series or using any other transformation skills. May I ask your recommendation about the any other possible way that I can achieve this goal? Thank you

Comment: I suggest that you write down explicitly the integral you want to calculate. Is it simply with respect to $ds\; dt$ on the rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,\pi]$ or is there anything else?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Yes. That is exactly what I want to do. You can find the full equation in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891721/transforming-an-integral-equation-using-taylor-series), which is my previous question.

Comment: OK, funny btw that you don't integrate $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ ? (which would probably make the problem much easier). Personally  I don't think Taylor will help on this.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh But even t goes up to 2pi, isn't the integration easily solved?

Comment: Not easily (unless I am missing something evident?). But easier because you may use complex analysis, integrating around a closed contour.

Comment: Perhaps I've missed something important, but why do we call the final term "g(x)" if there is no "x" in the entire problem?

Comment: @Merkh Oh yeah, that is my mistake again. Thank you for the correction

Comment: @H.H.Rugh You mean when I do the integration directly right? It would be easier than using the Taylor expansion? But for me, I cannot do the integration straight away even the t goes up to 2pi.

Comment: If the $t$-integral is really from 0 to $2\pi$ then I suggest that you correct your previous post (on the integral) and ask again. I guess that you would get some useful answers then.